# How to detect ranges of IDs with the same number of records inside them

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In a SQL SERVER 2005 database, please suppose we have a table called RUNNING_COLA_IS_AFRICA.

This table has a unique varchar(50) field called RUNNING_ID.

We have 1 million records in this table.

I would like to write a query that, sorting by RUNNING_ID ASC, and stating a range of 50, produces an output similar to the following:

```
RUNNING_ID_START RUNNING_ID_END
000000           000103
000104           000767
000892           001492
001576           011222
012345           013579
```

This means that:

```
a) The number of the records between 000000 and 000103 is 50;
b) The number of the records between 000104 and 000767 is 50;
c) The number of the records between 000892 and 001492 is 50;
d) The number of the records between 001576 and 011222 is 50;
e) The number of the records between 012345 and 013579 is <= 50.
```

Of course, min(RUNNING_ID) = 000000 and max(RUNNING_ID) = 013579 because they are ordered by RUNNING_ID ASC.

How could I achieve this in SQL SERVER 2005?

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH
  sequenced
AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY running_id) - 1 AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    RUNNING_COLA_IS_AFRICA
)
SELECT
  sequence_id / 50     AS group_id,
  MIN(running_id)      AS running_id_first,
  MAX(running_id)      AS running_id_last,
  COUNT(*)             AS size_of_group
FROM
  sequenced
GROUP BY
  sequence_id / 50
```

Comment: Excuse me!  The first has 49 records, the last has 36 records, and all the others have 50 records.  Is there any way to force the first range to have 50 records?

Comment: @UltraCommit - May bad, sorry.  Added `- 1` to make the first record be 0, and so the first group will have 50 constituents.

Comment: I have added a ORDER BY group_id ASC ;-)